# Restangular not able to get() my response

Tags: json, angularjs, restangular

I am trying to use Restangular. From the server side i am getting the below response:

```
[{"myModules":[{"code":"MODULE_Test","features":[],"name":"Testing"},  {"code":"MODULE_ADMIN","features":[],"name":"Portal Admin"}],"otherModules":  [{"code":"MODULE_ASSET_EFF","name":"Asset"},{"code":"MODULE_CARE_PATTERN","name":"Care Pattern"},{"code":"MODULE_NETWORK","name":"Network"},{"code":"MODULE_PERFORMANC","name":"Performance"},{"code":"MODULE_POADM","name":"Portal"}]}]
```

I am not able to fetch that response on the client side. Below is my code.

```
         Restangular.all('/rest/authorization/getData').getList()
         .then(function(user){
                var people = user;
            },function(error) {
                alert('testing');
                error.log("Error with status code", response.status);
            });
```

When i debug and see the value inside 'people' variable 
i cannot see my json response. I can only see:

```
addRestangularMethod: bound fetchFunction()
all: bound fetchFunction()
allUrl: bound fetchFunction()
clone: bound fetchFunction()
customDELETE: bound fetchFunction()
customGET: bound fetchFunction()
customGETLIST: bound fetchFunction()
customOperation: bound fetchFunction()
customPOST: bound fetchFunction()
customPUT: bound fetchFunction()
doDELETE: bound fetchFunction()
doGET: bound fetchFunction()
doGETLIST: bound fetchFunction()
doPOST: bound fetchFunction()
doPUT: bound fetchFunction()
fromServer: true
get: bound fetchFunction()
getList: bound fetchFunction()
getRequestedUrl: bound fetchFunction()
getRestangularUrl: bound fetchFunction()
head: bound fetchFunction()
length: 0
one: bound fetchFunction()
oneUrl: bound fetchFunction()
options: bound fetchFunction()
parentResource: null
patch: bound fetchFunction()
plain: bound fetchFunction()
post: bound fetchFunction()
putElement: bound fetchFunction()
remove: bound fetchFunction()
reqParams: null
restangularCollection: true
restangularized: true
route: "/restServices/authorization/getData"
several: bound fetchFunction()
trace: bound fetchFunction()
withHttpConfig: bound fetchFunction()
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Though i am able to see json response in my network tab in google chrome.

Comment: Your length is zero, so it is not seeing an array returned. Normally, you would use people[0] to access your data since it seems to be an array of one element.

Comment: Thanks Mike. The actual issue was i have configured addResponseInterceptor and i was not returning anything. As soon as i 'return data' it started working.